# IIS 6.0 command line set execute permissions

Tags: command-line, iis-6

I am looking for a way to set permissions on a virtual directory through command line.
I have a website setup with scripts only permission, but one of the child virtual directories needs to have scripts and executables.

So far, I haven't found a command line option to change the permissions for 6.0 - I saw the chacess command for 5.1 but it is not available in my system...

Is there an equivalent or another function that can do this for me?

Thanks, 
Christy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it  :-)

In case anyone else needs the information - here goes:

use the adsutil.vbs script (usually under inetpub/adminscripts) and type

> adsutil.vbs set w3svc/[site id]/AccessExecute "True"

The [site id] is the unique id IIS gives your site.  I found another script that gives the site number and name in a nice output:

http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2005/12/08/346.aspx

Hope this helps!
Christy

Comment: Note: if you are setting a virtual directory - at least the way mine is set up  the command is
> adsutil.vbs set w3svc/[site id]/root/[virtual directory]/AccessExecute "True"